# Delete a buffer and all traces of it in vim

Tags: vim

Is there vim command (or plugin) to delete a buffer and all traces of that buffer? Including, for example, .swp files, undo files, backup files, and so on?

Comment: You could create one, but it doesn't exist natively.

Answer (score 0):

We use `bdel` to unload a buffer from buffer list.
You can give

```
    :bdel %
```

to unload current buffer.
To unload alternate buffer, you can give

```
   :bdel #
```

For unloading other buffers, you can enter their numbers like `:bdel 1`. (By giving `:buffers`, you will get all the buffers, you can check the number of each buffer)

To completely delete a buffer and its related things like marks and options,

```
    :bwipeout
```

is used.

For swapfiles, backup , we have different commands like `:set nobackup`, `:set noswapfile`.
 If you have enabled both of them for all files and want to delete only for current buffer, you can do that also.

There is a auto command for it.

```
      :au BufDelete *.*  {cmd}
```

( {cmd} refers to any command you execute in command line. `au` refers to auto command.
 Whatever commands you give in the above one will be executed whenever a buffer is deleted. You can create your own functions for deleting its swapfiles and backups and call it the above auto command.)

Comment: I do have backup and swapfile set for all files (and want to delete them for only the current buffer). You say "you can do that also," but how do you actually do that? (that's my question). Are you saying that I should :au BufDelete * [some command that identifies and removes backups and swap files]? If so, what command catches everything? Also, is there a forward-proof command (so that I don't need to, e.g., remember to add "remove undo files too" to the autocmd when I enable undo files)?

Comment: OK. I will add them in the answer :)